# enviar variable de PHP a JS

Tags: php, javascript

intento pasar una variable de PHP a JS, he probado de todas las formas y no consigo resultados..que hago mal???

Segun la consola de firefox 'Uncaught SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break'.

```
 <?
    $firma=substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10);
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
function enviarDatos(){
 
var firma =  "<?php echo $firma; ?>";
alert(firma);
  
 var operario=document.getElementById("Combobox1").value;
 var fechaI=document.getElementById("Editbox1").value;
 var fechaF=document.getElementById("Editbox2").value;
 var cadena= operario+Math.floor(Math.random() * (20- 19)) + 20;

}


</script>
```

en el código fuente de la página, veo el error:

> onclick="enviarDatos('
>  **Notice**:  Undefined variable: firma
> in **C:\xampp\htdocs\vacacionesTablet\firmaVacaciones.php** on line
> **77**
>  ')"

y esta es la linea 77

```
<input type="button" id="Button6" onclick="enviarDatos('<?php echo $firma; ?>')" name="generar" value="Firmar" style="position: absolute;top: 465px;left: 500px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:11;">
```

y esta es la variable en PHP:

```
<?php 
   $firma=substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10);
........
........
........
?>
```

Gracias anythingg Solucionado....

Comment: Revisa el código fuente en el navegador, ahí te vas a dar cuenta de qué es lo que está mal; si no, copia la línea donde aparece el error y agrégala en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que tienes algo parecido a esto

```php
<input type="button" id="Button6" onclick="enviarDatos('<?php echo $firma; ?>')" name="generar" value="Firmar" style="position: absolute;top: 465px;left: 500px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:11;">
<?php $firma=substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10); ?>
```

**Estás tratando de acceder a la variable antes que se defina**, por ende, te arroja dicho error:

Ahora, te pongo en un contexto totalmente diferente para que me entiendas mejor:

> Imagínate que quieres una moneda, pero esta está a 1km de ti y no puedes moverte

Por ende, no puedes acceder a ella ni a sus datos, esto es lo que está pasando

Además estás abriendo *PHP* con `<?` y no con `<?php`, esto da una diferencia ya que así la variable no se definirá

### Solución

Cambia las líneas

```php
<?php $firma=substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10); ?>
<input type="button" id="Button6" onclick="enviarDatos('<?php echo $firma; ?>')" name="generar" value="Firmar" style="position: absolute;top: 465px;left: 500px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:11;">
```

Tengo lo siguiente:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$firma=substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10);
?>

<input type="button" id="Button6" onclick="enviarDatos('<?php echo $firma; ?>')" name="generar" value="Firmar" style="position: absolute;top: 465px;left: 500px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:11;">

<script type="text/javascript">
    
function enviarDatos(){
 
var firma =  "<?php echo $firma; ?>";
alert(firma);
  
 var operario=document.getElementById("Combobox1").value;
 var fechaI=document.getElementById("Editbox1").value;
 var fechaF=document.getElementById("Editbox2").value;
 var cadena= operario+Math.floor(Math.random() * (20- 19)) + 20;

}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Puedes probarlo y verás que funciona perfectamente, si el orden de las líneas está correcto, el error es que estás abriendo *PHP* con `<?` y no con `<?php`

**De manera que la solución sería:**

```php
<?php $firma=substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10); ?>
<input type="button" id="Button6" onclick="enviarDatos('<?php echo $firma; ?>')" name="generar" value="Firmar" style="position: absolute;top: 465px;left: 500px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:11;">
```